# Why is this newline in cURL command not working?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, curl

I am using GNU parallel with the `curl` command.

```
parallel xargs -n1 -P 10 curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{url_effective}: %{http_code}\n' < url.lst > out.csv
```

The `\n` character is not working. The output is coming in a linear fashion and not on another line.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it work without `parallel`? If multiple processes are writing to the same output (terminal or file), their output may appear in a weird order, e. g. a output coming from once process may be interleaved at arbitrary locations with output from a different process and not just on line breaks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster yes it did work without parallel.

Comment: Alright, then we found the culprit. You may be able to work around that with [`stdbuf(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/stdbuf.1.html). Could you please try that command with `stdbuf -o L -- parallel ...`.

Comment: Sorry, but the culprit is not stdbuf, but missing -q and the extra xargs. I have now tried twice to put this as an answer, but it gets removed by sudodus, Eric Carvalho, guntbert, David Foerster, Elder Geek, Zacharee1, so please complain to them if you do not get an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the `-q` flag (and removing xargs) fixes the issue of the `\n` special character not working in you command. Here is the new command:

```
parallel -qP 10 curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{url_effective}: %{http_code}\n' < url.lst > out.csv
```

As the `-q` flag is explained in the [man page for parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html):

```
--quote
-q
Quote command. This will quote the command line so special characters
are not interpreted by the shell. See the section QUOTING.
Most people will never need this. Quoting is disabled by default.
```

Comment: You posted the exact same answer yesterday and asked to explain the what and how this works in fixing the OPs answer. "Please explain what this command would do, why it would solve the OP's problem and where/when to execute it. This answer is quite vague and people are expected to just copy and paste without knowing what it's doing."

Comment: @KevinBowen Yeah, I remember adding that as a comment. I even have a [screenshot](https://s27.postimg.org/gwcizadkj/commentduplicate.png) of it having been deleted. The same comment that I put there applies here. Please elaborate on your answer and how to apply it to the OP's problem.

Comment: @KevinBowen The change does what the OP asks for: making the \n work. The place to execute is of course the same place as the OP would execute his command. Please explain why this is not obvious to you. The only change of OP's command is (as mentioned) removal of xargs and adding -q.

Comment: I assume that explaining what -q does in not needed as it is described in 'man parallel' under -q. But if you are too lazy to do 'man parallel', let me do that for you, too: "Quote command.  This will quote the command line so special characters are not interpreted by the shell. See the section QUOTING. Most people will never need this.  Quoting is disabled by default."

Comment: @OleTange See, adding this info within the body of the answer would make it a useful and more complete answer for people other than the OP in the future. I don't know what to tell you if you feel put out by folks asking for clarification on an answer that was already deleted once for being unclear. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinBowen I have to ask again:  Please explain why this is not obvious to you. So that I can learn, how you think.

Comment: @KevinBowen OP ask: "The \n character is not working. How can I fix this?" and I answer "-q (and removing xargs) fixes it." Now please explain why it is not obvious that the place to execute the command is the same place, and why it is not obvious that -q is described in 'man parallel'. I really want to learn why you do not find it obvious, because it is _really_ obvious to me.

Comment: @OleTange If you are OK with my edit, we can delete this comment thread. I even upvoted it ;-). Cheers.

Comment: Because an answer that says "do this" without explaining why is a crappy answer, and saying the answer is in the manual is essentially an RTFM answer, which aren't welcome here.